# iTextSharp check RadioGroup field

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net, itext

I have a PDF with radiogroup field and I want to select programmatically a radio within that radiogroup.

Ayone can help please.

Thanks

Comment: The question is unclear. A correct answer was given, but apparently the person asking the question doesn't believe the author of the software he's using.

Answer (score 1):

In Java: http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=122

In C#: http://kuujinbo.info/iTextInAction2Ed/index.aspx?ch=Chapter06&ex=FillDataSheet

It's as simple as this:

```
form.SetField(key, value);
```

Where `key` is the name of your radio field, and `value` one of the possible values of your radio group. If you don't know which values are possible, take a look at the following example:

Java: http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=121

C#: http://kuujinbo.info/iTextInAction2Ed/index.aspx?ch=Chapter06&ex=FormInformation

```
string[] states = form.GetAppearanceStates(key);
```

Comment: Hi,
I think I was clear in my question.
I know exactly how to fill a form in PDF.
My question was: how to select a radio in a radiogroup?

Thanks

Comment: Well, if the value of the radio in a radio group with name "Color" is "Red", you need to select it the same way you would set any other field: form.SetField("Color", "Red"); With this line, you select one specific radio button. I don't understand how I could interpret your question in any other way.